# Telerik Radcalendarview inline event click problem in xamarin android version 9

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, telerik

We are using Telerik calendar in our  application(Xamarin android). So far it was working smoothly.But when we deployed it on android version 9 , then the problem happened.

Point to be noted that , we have set `calendarView.EventsDisplayMode = EventsDisplayMode.Inline`.

When click on inline events, the app crashes.

While debugging, what we found out that, it is giving error  'Invalid Region Op -only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed' when deployed on mobiles having version 9, but it is working fine up-to android Version 8.

A point to note, calendarView.EventsDisplayMode = EventsDisplayMode.Popup is working fine across all versions.

Comment: Can you show us the Stacktrace and error message as otherwise we would be just speculating

Comment: Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Region.Op - only INTERSECT and DIFFERENCE are allowed occurred